# Google Script – Forms Submission behavior change

Tags: google-apps-script

I've had the simple function written in Google Script that was triggered on Form submission in a Google Sheet:

```
function setDelta(e) {

    ...

    var odoSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("SheetName");
    ...
}
```

Suddenly it started throwing an error that **"e" is undefined**

[image]

And indeed it is undefined, though it has been working for at least 2 years daily.

I was trying to debug, read the changelog, but to no avail. Please suggest what might be the issue here.

Comment: `e.source` is not a valid [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) for the "form submit" _Sheets_ trigger. Can you provide more information? Show us the trigger, more complete code?

Comment: The trigger is attached to the Google Sheet, so event source here is valid https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

setDelta function is set as a trigger for form submission. 

Again, it has been working daily for at least 2 years.

Comment: It isn't listed in the [form submit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit), but it does seem to be provided. However, we still need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: Ok, let's put it this way.

    function doStuff(e) {
          Logger.log(e.triggerUid)
    }

This code doesn't work as well. Somehow event isn't passed in Google Sheets triggers on Form Submission. However it works on Sheet edit. The code is fine, the environment is broken

Comment: @NikSka Try deleting the onFormSubmit  trigger and reinstall it again. Also,Provide screenshot of your current triggers. And Executions(view>executions)

Comment: How exactly are you triggering the code? Also, try using `console.log(JSON.stringify(e));` instead of `Logger.log()`. You can view those logs in the View > Stackdriver Logging

Comment: As I told you, it is a Google Sheet script that is being triggered on **Form Submission** event. This way the event.source is the Google Sheet itself. 

Strange thing is that all the logging completely stopped for me right now.

Comment: @Diego removing and reinstalling trigger worked! Seems like I've missed it as the most obvious step (turn on and off). Sorry for spending your time, you are great.

Comment: @Diego BTW, can I contact you directly to discuss Goggle Script development? I would like to commission writing a couple of scripts for my business to a professional.

Comment: Thank you but that suggestion was made by @I'-'I

Comment: @Diego well, anyway, from your profile I see that you are experienced in GoogleScript.

Comment: @I'-'I thanks for your suggestion! It worked.